# R Function defined in gloabl environment not visible in subsequent function

Tags: r, function, environment

I have defined four functions. I have executed the code for each and all four appear in the global environment when I call ls().
The first two are used inside the third and this works as expected. However, when I call the third function from the fourth function I get an error message telling me that **curent_month** doesn't exist.
(I eliminated all code from the fourth function as the failure occurs at the first statement, so the rest is not relevant.)
I have always understood that any object defined in the global environment is available to any sub-environment (i.e., inside a function).
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
## Function returns the most recent month having billing revenues
current_month_POSIX <- function(x){
  ## Fetch current month name for use in label below
  current_month_POSIX <- x  %>%
    filter(Year == 2020) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Billing)) %>%
    select(Month) %>%
    unique()%>%
    arrange() %>%
    tail(1) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    as_datetime()
  return(current_month_POSIX)
}

current_month_name <- function(x){
  current_month_name <- x %>%
    filter(Year == 2020) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Billing)) %>%
    select(Month, month_name) %>%
    unique()%>%
    arrange() %>%
    tail(1) %>%
    select(month_name) %>%
    substr(.,1,3)
  return(current_month_name)
}

curent_month <- function(x){
  POSIX <- current_month_POSIX(x)
  name <- current_month_name(x)
  return(list("current_month_name" = name, "current_month_POSIX" = POSIX))
}

### Function to reduce source data to clustered bar chart table
clustered_bar_data <- function(x){
  latest_month <- current_month(x)
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like it should work with the proper input. Can you make your question reproducible by providing some sample data that this should work with? We can't really help debug without anything to test it on...

Comment: It's an unusual style choice to call the return value of each function the same as the function name. Makes it hard to tell where the problem is. Perhaps when you call function #4, function #4 errors because it can't find the function `current_month_name()`, or perhaps `current_month_name()` is called but it runs into a problem defining its object of the same name, and the problem is that the `current_month_name` function can't find the object `current_month_name` when it tries to `return(current_month_name)`. Can't tell without something to test on, but you might consider renaming for clarity

Comment: Many style guides recommend giving functions verbs as names, which would suggest renaming the functions to, e.g., `get_current_month_name`.

Comment: I'm making some progress. I'll update tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_month` *does not exist*! You named your function `curent_month`.

Comment: I redid the function names and that sorted the problem. Thanks.